# prevent double login for my users

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a website (mysite.com) that I manage that has a login system in place.  Within that login section, I have a link to an external site (externalsite.com) that shows data and reporting.  I don't have control over this external site.  The problem is that my visitors have to login on my site, go to this page that shows a link to the external site and click it.  Then they go to this site and have to login again.  Well this is a big pain for my visitors, and I need to solve it.  My users are not the most tech savvy, so this extra login is very inconvenient to them.  Here's my plan:

(1) Normal login on mysite.com that sends them to welcome page
(2) In my users table in my database on mysite.com, I have a column for externalusername and externalpassword.  I either populate these manually myself or build a quick form for the user to input his login credentials *just once* and save them in my database.
(3) On welcome page I use those two columns and print something like:

```
<form action="https://externalsite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="joeusername">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="deepsecretpassword">
<input type="submit">
```

(4) Then the user just clicks submit and is sent to the other site.

Does this sounds prudent? Are there any problems with this?  I just wrote a little html page to test this and it works fine.  I've never had a form POST to a different domain, but I guess it seems to work.  I know I'm sending the login/password to the browser in plaintext, so there is a slight security issue there, but I don't think it's really a big deal.  Finally, externalsite.com could change their expected POST such that the login should be called `login` as opposed to the above `username`.  I don't think this is an issue as these things don't really change, and if they do, I just have to catch it and adjust the php or whatever that prints that html.

Am I missing anything?  I guess I just don't feel 100% comfortable since I have no control over externalsite.com.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you don't have control over external site, how do you know that sending the inputs will work? Do you have documentation about the site's interfaces?

Comment: @Alfabravo: OP stated "wrote a little html page to test this and it works fine"

Comment: Yikes, forgot to put on glasses. Sorry... so yes, send data as the external site expects it. If security is not of concern, go for it

Comment: @Alfabravo - yeah, I just did view source of the normal login page and took the input parameter names from there and it seems to work.  No I don't have any documentation from externalsite.com, nor do I know if they condone doing this.  Though, if they really wanted to prevent this, you could just check the referring page to make sure it's coming from their site.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a slight tweak:

- After normal logon to mysite.com, user is sent an interstitial page that gives a message along the lines of "Logging into external site" (this page should be delivered via https as it will contain the user's login info).
- The form on the interstitial page immediately submits itself to the external site via javascript.

This makes it even more convenient for the user and will feel like they are logging in just once. Other than that, you seem to be aware of the possible contingencies and will be able to handle them should they arise.

Comment: k, I like the https stuff, that makes things safer and more secure.  But I don't see how this heightens the user's experience. It seems like in my design, the user wants to go to their report on the other site, they click the button and boom, they are there as quick as possible.

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand.  There are things on mysite.com that the user might want, and he might not necessarily want to go to externalsite.com.  Are you proposing just sending him to externalsite.com after he logs into mysite.com with the javascript stuff?  I don't want to automatically do that, but you are correct, it would save a click if I wanted to.  Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes. The auto-submit is if they need to login there every time. If not, you can just skip that part.

Comment: +1 for a good idea, but not applicable to my specific situation